# Transfering v8 types to c++ types (string)

Tags: c++, node.js, string, types, v8

I am making a c++ addon for node.js and I am struggling with passing and getting data. I understood how to transform v8::Number to double, double to v8::Number and int to v8:Number, but I need some more. Mainly, v8::String to std::string and back, v8::Number to int and v8::Array to Array and back. Also it would be great to transfer js objects to some c++ variables, but it is less necessary. Does someone know, how to do that?
P.S. I looked over docs and I found nothing about arrays and objects and only this `string a (*v8::String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString()))` according to strings. But it does not work, I get an error `error C2660: v8::Value::ToString: function does not get 0 arguments` and `error C2512: v8::String::Utf8Value: no suitable default constructor`. I do not have any more ideas how to implement that. Can someone help?
And also I tried to do something with returning data from c++. In this way `args.GetReturnValue().Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "world").ToLocalChecked());` it works, but if I make like this:

```
    string s = "world";
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, s).ToLocalChecked());
```

I get an error `error C2664: "v8::MaybeLocal<v8::String> v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate *,const char *,v8::NewStringType,int)": cannot convert argument 2 from "std::string" to "const char *"`

And I have no idea what is wrong here. Did someone has exprience working with c++ addons and v8 types, How to do that?

Comment: What is not clear in the error message `cannot convert argument 2 from "std::string" to "const char *"`?

Comment: It is clear, but I want to convert string (not const char *)to v8::String(also not to const char *) to give it to node app.

Comment: hm.. it workes. Thanks a lot.  I will read about this function, never used it before. Returning strings works now. But how to get strings (trasform v8::String in args[0] to std::string)

Comment: Read the manual https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/d2/db3/classv8_1_1_string.html#afa0ba28edd1c162808e577df64f644ab

Comment: I read it and tried using writeUtf8, but it gives the same error on this function: `function does not get 0 arguments`

Comment: Ask a new question with your further attempt. Comments on SO are not for absolutely different questions.

Comment: It is the same question: how to transform v8::String to string and other types transformation.

Comment: P.S. I tried to copy `char *  buffer,
int  length = -1,
int *  nchars_ref = NULL,
int  options = NO_OPTIONS ` from there and put as args of writeUtf8, but then it gave even more errors.

Answer (score 0):

For understanding `v8::String`, the latest version of the docs help: https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-14.1/d4/d1b/classv8_1_1_string_1_1_utf8_value.html (some signatures have changed a bit since the days of Node 0.8 -- learning how to make sense of the compiler's error messages is highly recommended if you want to develop with C++!).

For understanding `std::string`, see some C++ documentation, e.g.: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string

If you need an actual example, you can look at V8's `samples/process.cc`, which has a function `ObjectToString` that converts any JS object (e.g. a `v8::String`) to a `std::string`. It's only two lines!